# bootstrap position fixed doesn't work with one column

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started making my new layout with bootstrap grid system i actually made rows and columns First row is my headerrow i embed the column in the header section 
i made a class in css and i put the position:fixed thing into it. then i added the class to the column. The class contains red background etc it works but the position:fixed doesnt work when i try to scroll down its just stays there. position:fixed; is outlined in chrome :/ why?

http://kephost.com/images/2017/07/07/riiiii.jpg
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: Your `position: fixed` is crossed-out in your element inspector. That means it's being overriden by a declaration with greater specificity or `!important`. Can you please double-check for any declarations that also target the element in question, and post **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: actually its targeted in bootstrap.css position:relative; i deleted it in google toolbar and now its not crosslined and it works. but... i cant delete it in the file because the bootstrap.css is linked not in a file form

Answer (score 0):

Because position: fixed has overrided by bootstrap's default position. col-xx-xx has a position: relative rule.

You do not need to add your class "headerUpper" to the bootstrap column. You should add it to it parents element. Like following code:

```
<div class="headerUpper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You also can use bootstrap's affix feature for fixed element - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix.

Comment: can u write the exact thing that i have to do? :/ i understand what are you saying that position:relative; by col overrides. but can u write it how can i solve it ?

Comment: Please see my new comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:fixed" 
      class="headerUpper col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-white"
>
```

It solved everything.